# SQL nested case with value differences between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have imported two Excel sheets as tables in Microsoft's SQL Server Management Server 2007, and they are both identical, except for the fact that they are from 2 different dates.

I'm looking to do 2 things that I'm struggling to do:

1. Calculate the monthly difference between values for the 2 tables which I can do with `cast`, and
2. inner join, but I'm not successful in using those values to be able to sum those values with a nested case like so:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(
          CASE WHEN ID <>'MISSING' THEN 
              CASE WHEN SUM(VALUE)>=0 THEN 
                   SUM(VALUE) 
              ELSE 
                   0 
              END 
          END)
   ```

I've tried many different ways, but one of the main errors I get is:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

The data would like so:

**dbo.Table1**

```
date(dd/mm/yy) | name |   id    | value
---------------+------+---------+-------
    1/1/14     |  A   | MISSING |  56    
    1/1/14     |  A   | MISSING |  -1    
    1/1/14     |  B   | YES     |  56       
    1/1/14     |  B   | YES     |  -1
```

**dbo.Table2**

```
date(dd/mm/yy) | name |   id    | value
---------------+------+---------+-------
    1/2/14     |  A   | MISSING |  24    
    1/2/14     |  A   | MISSING | -11    
    1/2/14     |  B   | YES     |  24       
    1/2/14     |  B   | YES     | -11
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete SQL statement? There should be a `from` clause, probably a `join`, and maybe a `group by`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `SUM` inside another `SUM`, just keep only the outer `SUM`. Also your outer `CASE` has no `ELSE` part, but you'd probably want to have 0 in that scenario as well, so why not use a single `CASE` condition?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ID <> 'MISSING' AND VALUE >= 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END)
```